# Changing default namespace

Tags: screwturn

We are using ScrewTurn Wiki for training purposes for our LMS.
Our LMS provider is updating the software om version x to y so we need to update the training materials in wiki to match a new version.
I thought that the easiest way to do it is:
 1. create a new namespace v10
 2. change the new namespace to serve as default (root)

I can't find a way to select or change a default namespace for wiki using admin pages. Is it even possible?

If it needs to be done programmatically, how can it be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible via configuration. You can rename namespaces, but root is built-in and has no name.

You could, however, use simple redirection tags to redirect from the old to the new namespace.